# ¿Como puedo solucionar el error Notice: Array to string conversion?

Tags: php

Al poner mi siguiente codigo en PHP solo me imprime la parte de "El animal es", alguna solucion? :(
Me marca el error de "Notice: Array to string conversion"

```
$Animals=Array("Gato","Perro","Panda"); 

    foreach($Animals as $animal){
echo "el animal es $Animals";
}
```

Comment: Estas colocando `$Animals` en el echo; debería ser `$animal`. Dentro de un echo solo se pueden imprimir `String`; `$Animals` es un arreglo.

Comment: El foreach ya te está iterando cada valor del vector y ese valor lo obtienes en la variable animal que es la que deberías imprimir en el echo

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, esa era la solucion!

Answer (score 0):

El error es que tienes un typo. En lugar de `$Animals`, que es el arrray, tienes
que escribir `$animal`

```
foreach($Animals as $animal){
    echo "el animal es $animal";
}
```